# Python social auth:Google login-error(user not allowed)

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am trying to include `login with google` service in my django project, for that i am using `social auth`.I have referred the following [link](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/11/02/google-apps-auth-for-internal-django-sites/) to do a sample example.

After entering my url `localhost:8000/secrets` it is redirecting to my google account and asking permissions to access my public data after i clicked `allow` it is redirecting to `localhost:8000/login-error` url and showing as 
`Authentication failed: User not allowed`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: tell me, did you tried different google account ?

Comment: @rajasimon, No i tried with only one that is my own account

Comment: @rajasimon, Yes now i tried but no change same problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem !!

looking at this code:

```
emails = setting('GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_EMAILS', [])
domains = setting('GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS', [])
if not emails and not domains:
    return True
if email in set(emails):
    return True # you're good
if email.split('@', 1)[1] in set(domains):
    return True
raise AuthFailed(backend, 'User not allowed')
```

Delete `GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_EMAILS` and `GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS` in setting,
the problem will be solved(for me)
try it~